# How to delete a file named --help?

Tags: rm

By mistake I created a file named --help trying to get help about the command >

```
> --help
```

If i try to delete the file like this:

```
rm --help
```

the help about the command rm is shown.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

almost last output lines of `rm --help`:

```
   To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use
   one of these commands:

          rm -- -foo

          rm ./-foo
```